# Lambda expression to find difference

Tags: c#, lambda, deferred-query

With the following data

```
string[] data = { "a", "a", "b" };
```

I'd very much like to find duplicates and get this result:

```
a
```

I tried the following code

```
var a = data.Distinct().ToList();
var b = a.Except(a).ToList();
```

obviously this didn't work, I can see what is happening above but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When runtime is no problem, you could use

```
var duplicates = data.Where(s => data.Count(t => t == s) > 1).Distinct().ToList();
```

Good old O(n^n) =)

**Edit:** Now for a better solution. =)
If you define a new extension method like

```
static class Extensions
{        

    public static IEnumerable<T> Duplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        HashSet<T> hash = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach (T item in input)
        {
            if (!hash.Contains(item))
            {
                hash.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can use

```
var duplicates = data.Duplicates().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Good solution with the hash set. I was thinking along those lines, but clearly haven't woken up yet...

Comment: Good solution with the hash set indeed! I knew I could do it that way, but didn't know it was possible to extend the language like that!

Answer (score 5):

Use the group by stuff, the performance of these methods are reasonably good. Only concern is big memory overhead if you are working with large data sets.

```
from g in (from x in data group x by x)
where g.Count() > 1 
select g.Key;
```

--OR if you prefer extension methods

```
data.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
```

Where `Count() == 1` that's your distinct items and where `Count() > 1` that's one or more duplicate items.

Since LINQ is kind of lazy, if you don't want to reevaluate your computation you can do this:

```
var g = (from x in data group x by x).ToList(); // grouping result
// duplicates
from x in g
where x.Count() > 1 
select x.Key;
// distinct
from x in g
where x.Count() == 1 
select x.Key;
```

When creating the grouping a set of sets will be created. Assuming that it's a set with `O(1)` insertion the running time of the group by approach is `O(n)`. The incurred cost for each operation is somewhat high, but it should equate to near linear performance.

Comment: I'd vote you up but require 15 rep in order to do that(!) Good example :)

Comment: You can change your prefered answer if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the data, iterate through it and remember the last item. When the current item is the same as the last, its a duplicate. This can be easily implemented either iteratively or using a lambda expression in O(n*log(n)) time.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, but learning how to write lambdas and it's not obvious to how to do it.