# What is the most efficient way of checking to see if an array of strings has any duplicates in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, string

I have a very, very large unsorted string array and i need to check to see if there are duplicates.

What is the most efficient method of checking this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138651/lambda-expression-to-find-difference

Comment: @tanascius that question is about finding the set of duplicates. This question is about establishing 'are there duplicates?', which is different.

Answer (score 5):

The *simplest* way is probably:

```
if (strings.Length != strings.Distinct().Count())
{
    // There are duplicates
}
```

That will be O(n) - but it won't tell you *which* items were duplicated.

Alternatively:

```
HashSet<string> values = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string x in strings)
{
    if (!values.Add(x))
    {
        // x was a duplicate
    }
}
```

Again, this should be amortized O(n).

Note that you can specify a different `IEqualityComparer<string>` if you want a case-insensitive comparison, or something like that.

Comment: Your second method is better for this asker, who wants the 'most efficient' way. `.Distinct().Count()` will examine every element, even when the very first two are duplicates (in which case we're done).

Comment: @AakashM: Indeed - as well as giving the duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list, and put each element in a sorted tree. This way, you can detect early whether there is a duplicate.

Comment: That ends up being O(n log n) in the case where there isn't an early "out" though.

Comment: It is roughly the same as your second solution.

Comment: Except that mine doesn't sort - leading to an O(n) solution instead of O(n log n). If you're only interested in equality, there's no advantage in sorting.